# Reset master to HEAD^ instead of HEAD and committed, how to recover?

Tags: git, git-reset

This is the state of the local branch before I did anything:

B<-A...

And this is the remote:

B<-A...

I was running `git add -A` on the repository and observed that it's taking too long. Turned out I hadn't ignored directory `v3` with large development artifacts. So I ran `git reset HEAD^` to get the index to look like what it did before running `add` and then added the `v3` directory to `.gitignore`, ran `add` again and committed the changes (call this commit C).

Git started complaining when I tried to push things to remote. Turned out by running `reset HEAD^` without having committed anything yet, I had jumped too far back in history and the local branched looked as below:

C<-A...

This creates a conflict where remote has B and local doesn't. The correct command I had to run was `git reset HEAD`. How do I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+reset+HEAD

Answer (score 1):

> So I ran git reset HEAD^ to get the index to look like what it did before running add

That should have been `git reset` (short for `git reset HEAD`)

Try `git reflog` to see what `HEAD` was before your git reset, and git reset to that commit.
Save first your work, just in case those commands don't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rebase your changes onto the remote branch.

Assuming you're working on `master`, with remote `origin/master`, just do:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

and that will move C after B instead of after A.